# Why aren't gradients not showing up on Heroku even with vendor prefixes?

Tags: css, heroku

I used the following css in my app. On development, it worked properly, on production, it failed to load the gradient. Here is the css I used which is not rendering:

```css
button {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( -135deg, rgb(255, 131, 10) 0%, rgb(255, 198, 54) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( -135deg, rgb(255, 131, 10) 0%, rgb(255, 198, 54) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( -135deg, rgb(255, 131, 10) 0%, rgb(255, 198, 54) 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 999px;
  width: 19%;
  height: 6vh;
  border: #ffffff 2px solid;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 2s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

What I see on all browsers is only grey/gray. Not a browser specific issue.

Here is a link to my app: [MP3Bolt](https://mp3bolt.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: you missed the important one which is the non-prefix one

Comment: Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-vendor prefix for gradients is missing.

```
linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color-stop2, ...)
```